# Act on Behalf of GitHub User With Supabase Auth

Tags: javascript, .net, authentication, github, supabase

I have a JavaScript browser app, and a ASP .NET Core Minimal API backend. The database is Supabase and the user authenticates with the GitHub Supabase auth provider.

The app, whether backend or frontend needs to 1) administer GitHub repos on behalf of the user and 2) query/update data in Supabase

I'm trying to figure out the way to achieve all this with the least authentication friction. Ideally, the user would register with their GitHub account, install the GitHub app in their GitHub account and give it access. Then, they would be able to create GitHub repos by clicking a button in the browser app.

I can authenticate the user with GitHub, but this access token only gives the user access to GitHub, and not Supabase. The user would need to sign in a second time to access Supabase.

I can authenticate the user with Supabase (GitHub provider), but this access token only gives the user access to Supabase. The user would need to sign in a second time to access GitHub or for the app to perform GitHub operations on the user's behalf.

So, I'm left wondering if there is a way to get an access token that allows the app to both query Supabase, and also perform GitHub operations on behalf of the user...

Is there really no way for the system to do both with a single access token? Is it necessary to sign in to two different systems to access either system?

Answer (score 0):

Supabase Session object has a `provider_token` and `provider_refresh_token` property that contains the provider's access token and refresh token, so once your user completes the OAuth login with GitHub, you can make request to GitHub's API using those tokens.
https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/blob/e659050ee0336527231b2149665887cd67898f33/src/lib/types.ts#L226